# A question involving the concept of Ratio and Proportion.

Tags: ratio

Question- There are 2 piles of cement and sand. The ratio of cement to sand in the first pile is 2:1 and in the second 3:1. What quantity of mixture has to be taken from each pile so that the result may contain 2150g of cement and 850g of sand?

My attempt- I assumed the total mass of the first file to be X and of the second to be Y. Given that the total mass of third pile is 2150+850=3000.
But then I am getting too many complicated expressions. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With units in grams (g), the first pile has $2x$ cement and $x$ sand. The second pile has $3y$ cement and $y$ sand. So you have 
$$2x+3y=2150,\\ x+y=850.$$
This can now be solved for $x,y.$

Once $x,y$ known, you may have to interpret what is meant by "what quantity of mixture from each pile".

Comment: I have got the answer. Thank u. It's 1200 and 1800